# Firebase Security Concerns

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I built this game in Swift that uses Firebase on IOS. My game needs to be able to access other users data to be able to modify in gameplay. How secure is my Firebase-Realtime-Database against access outside the game to either corrupt my database or modify user records? I have my authentication rules if Auth != nil, user can read or write anywhere. Do I need to be concerned about someone reverse engineering my Swift IOS app and getting database specific access information?

Answer (score 1):

Do you **need** to be concerned?  That depends entirely on whether or not you trust your users.

Strictly speaking, if your entire database is gated only by a single read/write rule that checks to see if the user is authenticated, then any user can decide to read the entire contents of your database, then wipe it all out pretty easily.  **If you don't trust your users**, then you will need to implement rules that  restrict what you think they should be able to do.

Comment: No I don't trust my users, because its a game and someone would want to hack to get an advantage. My question is would they be able to hack the IOS app in a way to be able to gain access to my keys, location of my database etc?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  Anything you ship in you app should be considered public information.